# Is uploading same app in the iOS app store (points to different server and has different name and icon) considered as spam?

Tags: ios, app-store

According to app store review guide:

`4.3 Spam
Don’t create multiple Bundle IDs of the same app. If your app has different versions for specific locations, sports teams, universities, etc, consider submitting a single app and provide the variations using in-app purchase.`

Spamming the store may lead to your removal from the Developer Program.

I have an app already in the app store which points to a specific base URL. Now I need to upload another app which will point to a different URL. **(Client requirement is there has to be two different apps).**

These two are essentially same app but they have different bundle identifier, name, icon and points to two different URL. Other than that all the features are identical. Does this fall in the Spam category?

If I submit my app and they reject it as spam are they going to remove me from the Developer program without warning/ remove the original app?

Comment: Nobody here can tell you with certainty. Some Apple reviewers will reject it, some won't - depends on if they see the other app. However, it certainly sounds like you are trying to do something explicitly against the review guide, so why risk it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's okay if you change the URL,Name and Icon. It would be great if you can add a custom launch screen and/or if you can modify app's color scheme, too. As the bundle identifier is different , it will considered an another app. I hope it will be accepted without issues